# How to remount a pen drive after having it "Safely Removed"

Tags: 11.10, mount, usb-drive

How can I (without removing the pen drive and connecting it again) mount a pen drive that I have "Safely Removed". T

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The USB design does not let you. `Safely remove` cuts the power to the device so there is no way to remount it until you replug it or reboot your system.

If it is not shown with ...

`ls /dev/disk/by-id`

it is gone.

Also found this one:

- [How to re-mount a USB stick after unmounting from Nautilus without disconnecting it?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/7051/how-to-re-mount-a-usb-stick-after-unmounting-from-nautilus-without-disconnecting)

Comment: Like always... feels like a sir

Comment: Not if pestilince's comment in the other answer is correct @Luis ;)

Comment: What pestilence mentions in his comment is totally correct but I tested the link he mentions and what the user Fussy mentions does not work for me. The device/1-1 appears only when I connect the device but if I "safely remove" it, the device folder disappears. So there is no way to echo a suspend/auto to it after doing that.

Comment: That's a shame Luis